# add new option into select with values from php

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-select

I want to add a dynamic select list, which contain my data from php. how should i do it? i also wanted to have arguments with variables from other php file e.g $mentor==$rows. appreciate it

```
<th><select name="mentor" style="width:95%">
        <?php
            $dbhost = 'localhost';
            $dbuser = 'root';
            $dbpass = '';
            $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
            mysql_select_db("testproject", $conn);

            if(! $conn )
            {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }

            $sql = "SELECT mtrname FROM mentors";
            $sql2 = "SHOW COLUMNS from mentors";
            $result= mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
            if(! $result)
            {
                die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            $fetchrow = mysql_fetch_row($sql2);
            $num = count($fetchrow);
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
                {
                     $rows[$i];
                }
            }   
            mysql_close($conn);
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $mentor?>" <?php if($mentor==$rows[i]) echo 'selected'?>><?php echo $mentor?></option>
        </select></th>
```

edited:
so i am trying to put select option into when the user first include the data. what i've tried is
`<?php
                $dbhost = 'localhost';
                $dbuser = 'root';
                $dbpass = '';
                $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
                mysql_select_db("testproject", $conn);
                if(! $conn )
                {
                    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }
                $sql = "SELECT mtrname FROM mentors";
                $sql2 = "SHOW COLUMNS from mentors";
                $result= mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
                if(! $result)
                {
                    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
                }
                $fetchrow = mysql_fetch_row($sql2);
                $num = count($fetchrow);
                while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
                    {
                     echo"<option value='".$rows[i].">".$rows[i]."</option>";
                    }
                }

                mysql_close($conn);
            ?>`

but it doesnt display anything from the mentor table. is my code incorrect or its my mysql database issue?

Comment: Move your option tag inside of the `for()` loop, current it's outside of the `while` loop so it has no reference to `$rows`

Answer (score 1):

You should move from mysql since it's not deperecated and move towards PDO or mysqli. If the results being returned are correct then you're pretty much there. Just move the `option` tag inside the `for()` loop.

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
    {
         echo "<option value='$mentor'". ($mentor==$rows[i] ? 'selected' : '') .">$mentor</option>";
    }
}
```

Comment: the mysql doesnt really matter because this is only for a college project. This is the only thing that doesnt work. Still doesnt work. Do you think its my database issue? Is my query/php correct?